# Monomial base change and the Vandermonde

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, determinants

Denote the falling factorials by $(x)_k=x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)$.

The [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) is given by $\det\left[x_i^{j-1}\right]_1^n=\prod_{i<j}(x_j-x_i)$.

It is well-known that in as much as the monomials $x^j$ form a basis (for polynomials), so do the $(x)_k$.

I would like to see why does the Vandermonde remains (almost) unchanged under the change of basis between the above two generators. More precisely,

> **Question.** Is there a conceptual reason for the validity of these evaluations?
>   \begin{align}
> \det\left[\frac{(x_i)_{2j-1}-(-x_i)_{2j-1}}{x_i}\right]_{i,j=1}^n
> &=2^n\prod_{i<j}^{1,n}(x_j^2-x_i^2) \\
> \det\left[\frac{(x_i)_{2j}-(-x_i)_{2j}}{x_i}\right]_{i,j=1}^n
> &=(-1)^n(2n)!\prod_{i<j}^{1,n}(x_j^2-x_i^2).
> \end{align}

Comment: What do you mean by a technical proof? The same argument as Vandermonde (vanishing for $x_i=x_j$ and also for $x_i=-x_j$, so we just need to look at leading coefficients) seems to do the trick, no?

Comment: You are right, the same trick works; I will edit the question.

Comment: The matrix entries $\dfrac{(x_i)_{2j-1}-(-x_i)_{2j-1}}{x_i}$ and $\dfrac{(x_i)_{2j}-(-x_i)_{2j}}{x_i}$ are polynomials of degree $j-1$ in $x_i^2$, right? Because if so, then the results follow from the "generalized Vandermonde determinant" (Theorem 2 in [my *A hyperfactorial divisibility*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/hyperfactorialBRIEF.pdf), and in many other sources) once you have computed the leading coefficients of said polynomials (which is not hard).

Comment: Yes, your results are general and interesting. On the other hand, those are equally provable (alternatively) using Dodgson's Method Condensation. So, my quest is not really in the proof but the conceptual (theoretical?) reason why they work.

Comment: Well, the conceptual reason Darij offered is essentially that if you add to each row (Or is it column in your case? It is too late here to figure it out now) any linear combination of the previous rows, the determinant does not feel it. How more "conceptual" do you want us to get?

Comment: Perhaps you are right, it might be unreasonable to ask much more than what has been said. Thanks.